# Want to open .exe files on a mac

Tags: macos, mono, exe

There is a file I would really like to use on my mac, but it is .exe and I cannot open it. It is called MCreator, and the file is mcreator.exe, and is used for making minecraft mods without knowing any java. I have tried numerous applications that supposedly can do this, such as wine, mono, and crossover, but none of them seem to work. When I use mono, I type in this, and it returns an error:
*Howards-Mac-mini:Mcreator 1.4.2 [1.6.4] Jared$ mono mcreator.exe
Cannot open assembly 'mcreator.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.*
When I use wine, it just quits and doesn't do anything, even though it displays the icon for MCreator. I cant figure out how to get open a preexisting file on crossover. Does anyone have any ways to fix my problems and/or run this file?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to run a virtual machine. Windows XP is good for this inside VirtualBox, as it can run on as little as 512mb of RAM, and 1 single-core virtual processor. Download VirtualBox by going to www.virtualbox.org and as for Windows XP, you can probably get your hands on that but I unfortunately cannot help with that unless you have a genuine COA.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble actually finding where I can buy the windows software, do you have a link?

Comment: You can purchase XP from places such as [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Windows-Professional-Service-Software/dp/B003CG00KE/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1398285567&sr=8-2&keywords=Windows+XP) Unfortunately I think that is all the help I can give on sourcing the software

Answer (score 0):

You could also try running it in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/). It allows you to run Windows apps in OS X without a copy of Windows. I've used it successfully before; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

1)Install Wine and Winebottler from http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

2)You may have to change the System Preferences >Security & Privacy>Allow Apps downloaded from>Anywhere

2)Run the xyz.exe using winebottler.